# Open Inbox of Email Client (Gmail, Outlook,etc) from android app

Tags: android, email-client

I have made an android application which uses firebase authentication. I am sending a verification email and want to show a button on my app that can launch a email client where the user can access there email to click on the verification link. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//Min SDK 15
            startActivity(intent);
```